# Euclidean geometry as left invariant metric on Bianchi groups of type I or VII0

Tags: geometry, manifolds, euclidean-geometry, lie-groups

According to [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#Euclidean_geometry_E3) on the geometrization conjecture, one of the eight possible geometric structures for a manifold is the euclidean, or $E^3$. The article on Wikipedia says that this geometry can be modeled as a left invariant metric on one of Bianchi's groups.

Unfortunately, the article has no more information on that, and I am looking for references, preferably on academic journals.

If anybody knows, could please let me know?

Comment: The Wikipedia article has several references, where this is discussed, e.g., William Thurston. Three-dimensional geometry and topology. Vol. 1. Edited by Silvio Levy.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde.